# Java Interface Comparator static compare

Tags: java, static, comparator

int    compare(Object o1, Object o2)
          Compares its two arguments for order.

For compare 2 objects o1 and o2 need do something like:

```
MyClass o1=new MyClass();
MyClass o2=new MyClass();

 if (o1.compare(o1,o2)>0) ......
```

Why this methtod not static?
 If method was static possible like:

```
 if (MyClass.compare(o1,o2)>0) ....
```

Comment: Jon's answer is right but your point is a good one.  In theory it would be handy if every comparable class had a static 'compare' method, but there's no way to enforce that through an interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it were static, how could it be called polymorphically? The point of `Comparator` is that you can pass an *instance* into something like `sort`... which has to then call the compare method *on the comparator instance*.

If a class is capable of comparing one instance of *itself* to another, it should implement `Comparable` instead, so you'd write:

```
if (o1.compareTo(o2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question shows a lack of understanding of `Comparable` and `Comparator`.

A `Comparator` is capable of comparing two other objects;

```
MyClass o1 = new MyClass();
MyClass o2 = new MyClass();
MyComparator c1 = new MyComparator();

if (c1.compare(o1, o2) > 0) {
  ...
}
```

Something which is `Comparable` is able to be compared to other objects;

```
MyClass o1 = new MyClass();
MyClass o2 = new MyClass();

if (o1.compareTo(o2)) > 0) {
  ...
}
```

It is very rare to compare a Comparator, so your example;

```
if (o1.compare(o1, o2) > 0) {
  ...
}
```

doesn't really make sense. Anyway, onto the answer, why isn't [`compareTo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) static? Basically, `Comparator` is an interface, and interfaces can't have static methods. Why? Well, it doesn't make sense for them. An interface is about defining a contract, but providing no implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of John is fine unless null pointers are possible. If you want to support null pointers an option is to define a static method on some Util class

```
// null pointers first
public static int compareTo(@Nullable Comparable v1, @Nullable Comparable v2)
{
    return v1 == null ? (v2 == null ? 0 : -1) : v2 == null ? 1 : v1.compareTo(v2);
}
// null pointers last
public static int compareTo(@Nullable Comparable v1, @Nullable Comparable v2)
{
    return v1 == null ? (v2 == null ? 0 : 1) : v2 == null ? -1 : v1.compareTo(v2);
}
```